# Iterating values fetched from mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

So I am creating a dynamic menu. Where I have stored the main categories of the menu in a separate table and subcategories in another table.
They are stored in this way

```
Categories Table
          id         cat_name
           1         HOME,
           2         PRODUCTS,
           3         SOLUTIONS,
           4         NEWS & GALLERY,
           5         DOWNLOADS,
           6         CONTACT
```

Right Now I am running a query

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$row['cat_name'];
$cat=explode(",",$row['cat_name']);
}
```

Then wherever needed I am printing the values like this

```
<?php echo $cat[0]; .. echo $cat[1]; //and so on ?>
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKHI6.png) right now. And it is supposed to look like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbcf4.png)
But the problem with this solution is that I have to define the index of the array to print it.

I am developing the admin panel for this one and I want that if the admin adds a new menu item then it should automatically fetch it and display it. 
But with this solution it is not possible.
I am thinking of iterating the values with a for loop but cannot get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in array then later access the values.

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $cat = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
       $cat[]=$row['cat_name']
 }
```

Now:

```
foreach ($cat as $category) {
     $cate_gory = explode("," , $category);
     foreach ($cate_gory as $categories) {
                 echo $categories . "<br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: That's what i am doing right now! But what I want is that if a new menu item gets added to the table it should also be displayed automatically. It cannot be achieved by printing the index of the array.

Comment: Edited my answer @PrakharSood

Comment: @PrakharSood FYI, the variable `$cat[$i]` represent each element in the array. So, when we echo it like that, all the values will be displayed one by one as per what you have like to do so.

Comment: Yes but i am applying the same for loop and it gives me all the values from the table at the same time. I can show you if you want

Comment: Isn't that what you want? To show all the values from the table? And saying all the values, I assumed that `values` pertains to `categories` @PrakharSood

Comment: Yes but not in a single go. I am uploading the images of the errors i am getting and how i want it to look. Check it out

Comment: Updated my answer @PrakharSood

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach ($query as $rows)

or

Use for ($i=0; $i < count($query); $i++)

Answer (score 0):

Probably You can try this also

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
 { 
    $row['cat_name'];
   $cat=explode(",",$row['cat_name']);
   foreach($cat as $catss) 
  {
    $cat = trim($catss);
    $categories .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way may be you wish like this for dynamic menu:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
     $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     $menu = '';
     $menu .= '<ul>';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
     { 
       $menu .= '<li>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</li>';
     }
     $menu .= '</ul>';
     echo $menu;
```

When you are fetching data from table then you can directly print that value using field name. if you want to further use that so, you have to add in one array like:

```
$cat[] = $row['cat_name'];
```

then you can use this value in that manner using for or while:

```
foreach ($cat as $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: That prints all of the values from the database in a single variable -_-

Answer (score 0):

## Foreach Loop

```
foreach($cats as $cat)
{
    echo $cat;
}
```

## Basic For Loop

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($cats); $i++) 
{
    echo $cats[$i];
}
```

## Simple Use Case

```
<?php

$cats = 'Stack overflow PHP questions';
$cats = explode(' ',$cats);
$html = '<ul>';
foreach($cats as $cat)
{
    $html .= '<li>' . $cat . '</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;

?>
```

## Your Code

In this case the while loop you are using will iterate over all the values returned from the sql statement, so there is no need to add more complexity. I would remove the commas from the field names and echo out the html this way.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$html = '<ul>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    $html .= '<li>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: The thing is this solution prints all the values in a single variable i.e $cats[$i] or in foreach loop's case $cat. It prints all the values from the table in a single variable which is not my aim.

Comment: How do you mean in a single variable?

Comment: Don't be confused it is a different variable every time, it goes through the array sequentially.

Comment: when i use the explode function to store the variable in $cat. When iterate the values stored in $cat using for loop it only gives the first value i.e HOME from the table. :/

Comment: That might be a different issue altogether, run the sample code I have above

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data coming back, it looks like you are making an array of arrays, in which case you might need two for loops...

Comment: Try the solution I just posted, and I would echo out the $row first to make sure you are using explode correctly.

Comment: Explode is working correctly. I have added the images in the question. Maybe by seeing it you might be able to judge the problem.

Comment: Try the updated code, you may only need a while loop. Forget the explode.

Comment: Not in a way I would like but works okay. Will be difficult in automation in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach ($cat as $val) {
    echo "<li>{$val}</li>";
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Instead of the `index`. Also this should be faster and readable than `for` loop.